# Convert string to array in php, output it and then output in ascending and descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have so far I have managed to convert a string to an array in php and out put it with a foreach and an echo statement. But when I try to sort it I get an error like this:

> Warning: asort() expects parameter 1 to be array.

In the text book I'm studying it shows an example like this:

```
sort($array[,$compare]).
```

I don't quite understand that. I don't want to use the `print_r` function. I just want to echo out the result So I've come here to ask for help. I appreciate any advice. Here is my code:

```
 <form action="list.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="names">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <?php

 if(!isset($name)) {$name = '';}
 if(!isset($names)) {$names = '';}
 if(!isset($value)) {$value = '';}
 if(!isset($myarray)) {$myarray = '';}
 $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
 $names = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'names');
 $myarray = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'myarray');
 if($myarray === NULL){
$myarray = array();
 }
 $myarray = $names;
 $name = explode(' ', $myarray);
 foreach($name as $value){
 echo ($value)."<br>";
 }
 $myarray = $names;
 $name = explode(' ', $myarray);
 foreach($name as $value){
 echo asort($value)."<br>";
 }
 $myarray = $names;
 $name = explode(' ', $myarray);
 foreach($name as $value){
 echo arsort($value)."<br>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You have to `asort()` the array, not the values (the arrays elements)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, no need to do anything with `$name` here:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
```

Also no need to do anything with `$myarray` here:

```
$myarray = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'myarray');
```

Or here:

```
if($myarray === NULL){
    $myarray = array();
}
```

Since you overwrite anything that could be in it here:

```
$myarray = $names;
```

And here you overwrite `$name`:

```
$name = explode(' ', $myarray);
```

No need to do this either, `$myarray` hasn't changed since receiving this value the last time:

```
$myarray = $names;
```

Sorting should be done on the array, not the values, and `sort()` is propably what you want here:

```
$name = asort($myarray);
foreach ($name as $value){
    echo "$value<br>";
}
```

And then the reverse sort:

```
$myarray = $names;
$name = arsort(explode(' ', $myarray));
foreach ($name as $value){
    echo "$value<br>";
}
```

So, for the complete code, somewhat simplified and shortened:

```
<form action="list.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="names">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php

// This is the only variable you are posting
// Also doing explode here
$names = explode(' ', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'names'));

// Store a copy of the array here so that we have the original unchanged
$myarray = $names;

// Printing out the array as is
foreach ($myarray as $value)
{
    // Double quotes to parse variables
    echo "$value<br>";
}

// Sort the array
sort($myarray);

// Print it out sorted
foreach ($myarray as $value)
{
    echo "$value<br>";
}

// Reverse the array
arsort($myarray);

// Print out again
foreach ($myarray as $value)
{
    echo "$value<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I was too hasty to post my last comment before I had explored my options. It was my typos that was causing the errors.The code you suggested works, and it works GREAT! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort before the loop.
I.e.

```
asort($name);
foreach($name as $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
$myarray = $names;
$name = explode(' ', $myarray);
arsort($name);
foreach($name as $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad I posted this problem, and I hope that anybody else struggling with php can see this and be helped.